# How to generate a sequence in maple based on a condition

Tags: maple

I'm supposed to generate a sequence of even numbers from $1$ to $100$ in Maple. While this should be very straightforward, I've tried using both a conditional statement within the $\text{seq}()$ command as well as a loop but got an error in both cases. I've looked at the structure for the loop and can't quite determine where my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the following:

```
> step := 2:
  upper := 100:
  seq(step*i, i=1..upper/step);  # 2*1, 2*2, 2*3, ..., 2*(100/2).
  seq(step..upper, step);        # 2, 2 + 2, 2 + 2*2, 2 + 3*2, ..., 100.
```

Answer (score 1):

You ought to prefer Adriano's answer.

However you seem to be learning Maple, and you did mention that you were unable to get a conditional to work within a call to the `seq` command. So I'll mention that can be done by using the so-called operator form of `if`.

```
seq( `if`( i::even, i, NULL ), i=1..100 );

seq( `if`( irem(i,2)=0, i, NULL ), i=1..100 );
```

Note that your question is about only programming in Maple rather than doing math in Maple, and so is off-topic in this forum. More appropriate would be www.stackoverflow.com or www.mapleprimes.com .

Comment: Wow, i didn't know you could add a criterion to seq( ). That's very useful. Can you explain why there is a NULL inside the `if`.

Comment: The first argument to the functional `if` call is the condition. The second argument is the return value (of the `if` call) if the condition is `true`. The third argument is the return value (of the `if` call) if the condition is not `true`. Sometimes it's handy to be able to specifiy that third argument as NULL, ie. nothing is contributed by the failing cases. Of course the above is a toy example; in practice one could generate the even numbers in better ways, eg. `seq` with a step of 2.